# Entry points to finance for Applied Mathematics (Numerical Analysis/High Performance Scientific Computing) PhD Student

Tags: finance, quants, books, career, papers

I'm looking to go into quantitative finance after my phd in around 2 years. With a background in pdes/numerics/heterogenous and distributed computing, I think my skill set is applicable in this area, and I'd enjoy the work. I don't have any financial background though, before my PhD I worked as a software engineer and data scientist at a couple of companies.

What entry level textbooks/papers/concepts should I start my (quant) finance journey with?

Are there any resources that mirror 'cracking the code interview' for quant finance that are recommended?

In general, I am less interested in quant dev jobs, unless they offer progress to research positions, as I don't want to be stuck in another developer job, I'd prefer to make use of my math skills.

It would be a great help to hear from other people with similar background on how they got started in the field, and which companies look favourably on these skill sets for their business - both in the Europe and the USA.

If it helps I am based in London, at a top 10 uni globally on the PhD in Math program, so for boxticking and geography I think I am ok?

thank you :)

Comment: This question is also relevant: https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/55249/848

Comment: Also this: [Pre-requisite math books, to the pre-requisite math needed to become a front desk quant](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/54509/21016)